# Editing domain for a eclipse model

Tags: eclipse, emf

Node is my eclipse model tree.If i want to get an editing domain for the Node will the following work:

```
EditingDomain domain= TransactionUtil.getEditingDomain(Node);
```

if not how can i get the Editing domain for the model if I donot have a IWorkbenchPart.?